Properties on targets - INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES - CMake on Qt Project
It is my first approach to CMake, I have been researching in all sources of information such as Qt Documentation, CMake.org and Stack Overflow, I have not cleared all my doubts and questions about this line of code:
get_target_property(includes Qul::Core INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

I understand the command "get_target_property ()" stores the value of the property of the target "Qul::Core" in the variable includes, however, I am still lost at the property on target "INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES".
I woud like to understand what does this property does in this specific line of code.
I am beginner in QT Platform, I would like to keep learning more about.
I am reading and reviewing the code found in link: Qt Quick Ultralite Motorcycle Cluster Demo
Research Links:
CMake Build System
CMake Developer
CMake Packages

CMake documents predefined properties in the cmake-properties page. E.g. property INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES is described here.
